# Broadcasting ios push notification platform wise

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, apple-push-notifications, swift4

I have a use case wherein i need to broadcast push notification for ios devices but in this, i need to send some notification for iphone and some different for ipad. How can we send this? Should we modify something in payload?
Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You should save each user device type against each user

`// for iPhone use UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)`

By this code you can check user's device.
Save the device type against each user to your backend(server).

Just run query to fetch iPad or iPhone user of your application.

Based on query, fetch their push ids and send your push.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but is there any way from client end itself i.e. from app code only, to handle this bifercation of platform?, i mean any modification in payload

Comment: What is exactly the change do you want in your notification ?

Comment: I want that some specific notifications should only be shown in iphone ,not in iPad and same vice-versa